# ForeignKey switching by user option in Django

Tags: python, django-models, django-admin

Lets look at the first app (is quite simple)

app name = family; models:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name       = models.CharFiled(max_length="30")
    title      = models.CharField(max_length="30")
    work_title = models.CharField(max_length="30")

class Child(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length="30")
    school_year = models.IntegerField(max_length="30")
```

Then I have another app that needs to have a foregin key to the 2 classes in family app depending on the user choice, lets look at the next example:

app name=persons, models:

```
class Info(models.Model):
    code          = models.CharField(max_length="30")
    family_member = models.CharField(max_length="1", choices=(('1', 'Parent'),('2', 'Child'),))
    person        = models.ForeignKey('family.???') #here is where I have the issue
```

how can I build the ForeignKey depending on the user choice in family_member? so if the user selects Parent (1) then the ForeignKey should point to Parrent class but if the user selects Child(2) then the foreignKey should point to Child

I'd like to search for solutions in models.py and not fix the issue in views - if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `GenericForeignKey` for that task. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/).

Comment: the docs turned out to be quite hard to fallow for me, I had toruble understanding how to use them in models not in shell so I've ended up finding this website: http://axiacore.com/blog/how-use-genericforeignkey-django/ that had a nice example. Your answer helped me understand what I need to look for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit Parent and Child from one class and make foreign key point to it:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length="30")

class Parent(Person):
    title      = models.CharField(max_length="30")
    work_title = models.CharField(max_length="30")

class Child(Person):
    school_year = models.IntegerField(max_length="30")
```

and in persons:

```
class Info(models.Model):
    code          = models.CharField(max_length="30")
    family_member = models.CharField(max_length="1", choices=(('1', 'Parent'),('2', 'Child'),))
    person        = models.ForeignKey('family.Person')
```

Although in this case user will be able to select child or parent independently from family_member choice, unless you filter choices for user by, for example, giving him only Child model objects to choice if he choose family_member 'Child' and vice versa.

Comment: the filtering for user by Child model will be implemented in the model? I hope I'm not asking to much if I ask for a code example